# when do we really benfit from java stream.unordered()?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream, java.util.concurrent

java streams has this method [`unordered()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#unordered()).

I am not sure when this method will really enhance the performance of the program.

1. `someList.stream.unordered()`  //here List is any way ordered and using `unordered()` is not going to make the list unordered, so the usage of `unordered()` has no effect.
2. `someSet.stream.unordered()` //here set is any way NOT ordered and hence using `unordered()` is not going to make the set any further unordered, so the uage of `unordered()` has no effect. Similarly for Map too.

While using `parallelStream` it may help though. But otherwise for NON parallelStream's is it required. Are there any such cases where it will boost performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A per the [documentation on stream ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Ordering) (emphasis mine):

> For parallel streams, relaxing the ordering constraint can sometimes enable more efficient execution. Certain aggregate operations, such as filtering duplicates (distinct()) or grouped reductions (Collectors.groupingBy()) can be implemented more efficiently if ordering of elements is not relevant. Similarly, operations that are intrinsically tied to encounter order, such as limit(), may require buffering to ensure proper ordering, undermining the benefit of parallelism. **In cases where the stream has an encounter order, but the user does not particularly care about that encounter order, explicitly de-ordering the stream with unordered() may improve parallel performance for some stateful or terminal operations.**

Comment: explicitly de-ordering the stream with unordered()  like `someList.stream.unordered()`, will this really have any effect as the underlying data structure still has ordered preserved. Ok for intermediate steam, it can, I agree. +1  Am I Right?

Comment: @samshers the point is that operations on ordered sterams may work under the assumption that the stream needs to stay ordered so will do extra operations to ensure that, while explicitly declaring the stream as unordered may avoid such overhead. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: right, that answers. So other way said, does the result/output have to be ordered in the same corresponding way as input. If this is not required, use `unordered()`. Right?

Comment: "In the same corresponding way" not only that: suppose you're using `findFirst`. If the stream is unordered and two elements of the stream are equal, you don't have any guarantee as to which one of the two is returned. It can matter for cases where `equals` ignores certain fields, for example. Think of it more easily: "does order *not* matter in any way and you need better performances? Then use `unordered`"